# Find Top of Information Store Folder in non-english language

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I am working with EWS API and noticing that while downloading the list of folders with MSFT, it doesn't show up the "Top of Information Store" folder in english langauage.

However, when I tried to locate the same folder using EWS Editor, I was able to see that, but in another language (Romanian).

Can someone help me in getting - on how I can find that info?

Answer (score 0):

"Top of Information Store" is a distinguished/wellknownFolderName folder msgfolderRoot so you can just do a bind to that folder directly eg

```
Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
```

or in the Graph its just

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/msgfolderRoot
```